# Count sent SMS messages

Tags: android

I have to count all sent text messages (SMS) by user or by some other app.

My app will run as Service (in background) and count sent messages.

Finally, when number of sent messages is greater than some value, I'll trigger an action.

Any idea on this ?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878910/keeping-count-of-the-number-of-smss-sent-in-android  take a look at this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoc can count SMS Sent by user or any other Appliction on device from listening  ***SMS ContentProvider*** by using [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)

for complete example how you can register `ContentObserver` for *SMS ContentProvider*  see in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520277/practical-way-to-find-out-if-sms-has-been-sent/9659025#9659025) my answer

Comment: Error in class SMSObserver on this line
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null,
      null, null);
//-------------------------------------------------------------
The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type SMSObserver

Comment: ok fine edit your post with latest code bez this is working as you see my answer was accepted by another user

Comment: Make sure you are creating this SMSObserver class inside your service or activity if you are creating outside from service,activity or broadcast receiver then you need to use current context instead of this.getContentResolver() so repace this line with Your_Current_Context.getContentResolver()

Comment: There's a call to onChange() whenever I send SMS, but also, function is called on received SMS.

Comment: Since google Play is trying to stop apps with READ_SMS permission unless for OTP or financial data purposes, I was wondering if there is another workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

This will be done by broadCastReceiver
Check this 
[Android - SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117701/android-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: There are no broadcast receivers for sent SMS messages.